# Get the file in which the function was declared in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm relatively new to Node.js.
I developed a script in Python, and now I want to convert parts of it to Node.js and as a result some gaps have been created that I will need to understand how to execute in Node.js:

1. How can I get through the function, the file in which the function was defined?

for example:

```
// a.js
function foo(){
    console.log("This is function 'foo' which is located in a.js file");
}

// b.js
function bar(){
    console.log("This is function 'bar' which is located in b.js file");
}

// main.js
// The desired function:
getFile(foo); // Will return the path of the a.js file
getFile(bar); // Will return the path of the b.js file
```

2. The reason I need to know the location of the file where the function was declared (first question), is to determine whether it is a function that the user wrote or whether it is a built-in function or an external module function.

So my second question is:
is there a way to determine the source of the function in the most deterministic way?

3. Is there a way to get all the existing functions? Including functions that were imported from modules and other files

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly with what you have tried so far.

Comment: A builtin function has no source that you can (or should) refer to

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that from within the function itself (or a function called by that function). But when you do have access to it, then you can use this trick:

```
console.log((new Error()).stack);
```

For example:

```
function foo1() {
  console.log((new Error()).stack);
}

foo1();
```

will print:

```
> node test.js 
Error
    at foo1 (/tmp/test.js:2:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/test.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```